# Issue with sorting a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c

I’m trying to sort a doubly linked list in ascending order using bubble sort in C. However, when I run my program, the output is blank. I suspect there might be something wrong with the logic of my sorting function. When I ran the debugger, it found an issue with the following code:

```
void sort_list(node** head, int n) {
    node** ptr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            node* p1 = *ptr;
            node* p2 = p1->next;
            if (p1->data > p2->data) { // Exception thrown: read access violation. **p2** was nullptr.
                node* temp = p2->next;
                p2->next = p1;
                p2->prev = p1->prev;
                p1->prev = p2;
                p1->next = temp;
            }
            ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me identify what might be causing this issue and how to fix it?
Update:

```
void sort_list(node** head, int n) {
node** ptr = head;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
        node* p1 = *ptr;
        node* p2 = p1->next;
        while (p2 != NULL) {//while loop added
            if (p1->data > p2->data) {
                node* temp = p2->next;
                p2->next = p1;
                p2->prev = p1->prev;
                p1->prev = p2;
                p1->next = temp;
            }
            ptr = &(*ptr)->next;//Exception thrown: read access violation.**ptr** was 0x10.
        }
    }
}
```

}
Changed i<=n to i<n, didnt do the trick, added a restriction while (p2!=NULL), that worked but another bug appeared I assume it is of same origin? What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mre] and [tour] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory: Guard for p2==null. (so `i` should probably not run all the way up to `n`, inclusive)

Comment: Lets say there is only one element in the list. `node* p1 = *ptr;` makes `p1` point to head and `node* p2 = p1->next;` makes `p2` point to null.  Then you use `p2` like this: `if (p1->data > p2->data)` but null doesn't have a data element so it crashes.  And the same thing is true of any length - it just has to loop a couple times.

Comment: It might be worth taking a step back (after fixing the bug already pointed out) and considering how much simpler it would be (in the case of small _payload data_) to simply swap the payloads between two nodes (as you would do if it were an array.) No muss, no fuss with pointers being reassigned... You could even drop the requirement of passing the count of the nodes (`int n`) ...

Comment: It is much more efficient to [merge sort](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/list_sort.c) a linked-list.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= n; ...)`, as mentioned previously, is a code smell as it runs n+1 iterations.  You almost always want `i < n` and once in while `for(i = 1; i <= n; ...)`.

Comment: Changed i<=n to i<n, didnt do the trick, added a restriction while (p2!=NULL), that worked but another bug appeared I assume it is of same origin?